# regex/sed example to spot numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have an input like this

```
this  
is  
3some  
137 test  
text
```

and want to extract just the numbers at the beginning.

I tried:

```
sed 's/![0-9]{1,}.*//1'
```

but this isn't cutting anything.

Thx in advance, I am pretty new to Linux at all but this page already helped me a lot!

Comment: `grep -oP "^\d+" filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use grep to extract stuff:

```
grep -oE '^[0-9]+'
```

o to get only the matched part instead of the whole line, E for the regex

sed is intended to do replacing.